# Datapoint Classification Accuracy

Tags: classification, cross-validation

I am interested in finding ways to quantify the certainty of correct classificaions for single datapoints. This is interesting for me since for clinical studies where we for instance would classify subjects with an without autism, it would be hugely helpfull to add to the diagnosis a certainty about the diagnosis.
So far I know about methods which assume a certain distribution for the data like naive Bayes Classifiers and the like. Generally, I am interested about hearing about all the approaches there are, and especially about quantifications which are interpretable as well as not specific to a unique trained classifier.
Every hint is very welcome

Comment: You mean metrics like precision, sensitivity, specificity?

Comment: No, I mean more a probability (or other measure of certainty) for the datapoint falling into the respective class

Comment: Precision = $Pr(Y = 1\ |\ \hat{Y} = 1) = TP / (TP + FP)$, e.g. the probability that the true class is positive if your model says positive. Sounds like what you need.

Comment: Hm, but then again, this is a quantification for the entire class. I am rather looking for the following: Imagine we use a Support Vector Machine and we have points classified, and their distance to the decision surface is obviously different. I would be interested in this case to be able to quantify what proximity to the surface means in terms of certainty for each single datapoint. Another example might be a Gaussian Naive Bayes where we again have a probability for each classified datapoint.

Comment: Precision-recall curves show precision and recall for every cutoff. They allow you to assess the precision (defined as in my previous comment) at the cutoff you want. The precision, sensitivity, specificity, ... of a classifier depend on the threshold you choose, exactly like you mention.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly, you have a probabilistic prediction for a **classification**, that is you make a prediction that the new patient will be autisitc with y% probability and and not autistic with probability (1-y)%.

In this case you may want to start with the concept of "scoring rules" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule which is the term used for the evaluation of how well a probabilistic prediction (in classification) is. A another usual term is "calibration".

Comment: that might be helpful. so what I am looking for is for instance something like the posterior probability for a single datapoint as given by a gaussian naive bayes classifier. I don't think accuracy etc. are what I am asking for at all. I am kind of amazed this problem is not wildly discussed..

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly, you are looking for the posterior probability for the data points. So, in principle you must be able to get this information if you used a probabilistic model for your classification be it naive Bayes or logistic or any simple regression. 
If this is what you are looking for, depending on what platform you program it is possible to obtain it. Let me assume that you use R:

In that case, you can first fit a nauve bayes model using 'naiveBayes' function in the 'e1701' package. And then using the 'predict' function, you calculate the posterior probablities of a point belonging to a particular class given the data. Here is a small pseudo code:

```
 library(e1701)
model=naiveBayes(Class ~ ., data = X) ## Here let X be a dataframe with one column named Class which is the class of the samples. 
predict(model, X, type = "raw")
```

Hope this helps... depending on what model you use, the predict function will take different arguments. Information about this can be found in the 'stats' package.